# Как заставить скрипт сразу же перезапускаться, после выполнения программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос, shutil

Программа нужна для бекапа сохранений игры каждые 5 минут. Беру дату и время, записываю в переменную  **x**, а позже в **name**. Создаю папку-шаблон и копирую в неё 3 файла сохранений, далее папку переименовываю в значение **name** и даю перерыв в 5 минут

***НО!***

Если зациклить выполнение функции, первый круг проходит отлично, на втором вылезает проблема -- папка-шаблон всё так же создаётся, но не переименовывается. И уже на 3 круге выходит ошибка, мол папка **savprot** уже существует

Ошибки не будет, если перезапускать скрипт ,а не циклить его. Но я не знаю как это сделать

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import shutil

x = datetime.now()



def backup():
    name = '{}.{}.{} _ {}.{}.{}'.format(x.day, x.month, x.year, x.hour, 
    x.minute, x.second)
    os.mkdir('C:\\WGsav\\savprot')
    shutil.copy2('C:\\ProgramData\\Orbit\\274\\RLD!\\Save001.sav', 'C:\\WGsav\\savprot')
    shutil.copy2('C:\\ProgramData\\Orbit\\274\\RLD!\\Save002.sav', 'C:\\WGsav\\savprot')
    shutil.copy2('C:\\ProgramData\\Orbit\\274\\RLD!\\saves.ini', 'C:\\WGsav\\savprot')
    os.rename('C:\\WGsav\\savprot', 'C:\\WGsav\\{}'.format(name))
    time.sleep(300)


backup()
```

С циклом:

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
import subprocess

x = datetime.now()



while 1:
    name = '{}.{}.{} _ {}.{}.{}'.format(x.day, x.month, x.year, x.hour, 
    x.minute, x.second)
    os.mkdir('C:\\WGsav\\savprot')
    shutil.copy2('C:\\ProgramData\\Orbit\\274\\RLD!\\Save001.sav', 'C:\\WGsav\\savprot')
    shutil.copy2('C:\\ProgramData\\Orbit\\274\\RLD!\\Save002.sav', 'C:\\WGsav\\savprot')
    shutil.copy2('C:\\ProgramData\\Orbit\\274\\RLD!\\saves.ini', 'C:\\WGsav\\savprot')
    os.rename('C:\\WGsav\\savprot', 'C:\\WGsav\\{}'.format(name))
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Пока решил проблему планировщиком задач, включаю событие, как захожу в игру

Comment: А вы не забыли поместить генерацию нового name с новой датой внутрь цикла?

Comment: от идеи цикла отказался, но когда он был, конечно же это предусмотрел

Comment: Если бы вы это реально предусмотрели, то никакой ошибки не было бы скорее всего. Лучше покажите ваш код с циклом, а мы найдём в нём ошибку

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: а я X забыл заново проинициализировать(засунуть в цикл)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте модуль subprocess.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'code.py'], start_new_session=True)
```

Таким образом, по завершению программа будет заново запускать сама себя.

Comment: Вместо code.py указывал имя скрипта, его относительный и полный пути

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл`

Comment: @Булат, найти, вероятно, не получается сам Python. Укажите его абсолютный путь.

Comment: Указал, всё заработало